# Get and Set properties doesn't change permanently c#, VS

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, get, set

I'm working on my c# pac-man game in visual studio.

I have a main sprite class and a subclass called User. The user should Set the x position and y position as it calculated it.

What my timer does:

```
 pictureBox1.Focus();
 paper.Clear(Color.Transparent);
 user.moveUser(keyValue);//Code1 shown below
 sprite.DrawSprites(paper);//Code shown below
 pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Code behind those Methods:

Code1:

```
public void moveUser(int mKeyValue)
    {

        switch (previousImage)
        {
            case false:

                switch (mKeyValue)
                {
                    case 39:
                        sprite.Image = imageArray[0];//left
                        sprite.XPos += stepsAmount;

                        break;
                    case 37:
                        sprite.Image = imageArray[1];//right
                        sprite.XPos -= stepsAmount;

                        break;
                    case 38:
                        sprite.Image = imageArray[2];//up
                        sprite.YPos -= stepsAmount;

                        break;
                    case 40:
                        sprite.Image = imageArray[3];//down
                        sprite.YPos += stepsAmount;

                        break;
                }
                previousImage = true;
                break;
            case true:
                switch (mKeyValue)
                {
                    case 39:
                        sprite.Image = imageArray[4];
                        break;
                    case 37:
                        sprite.Image = imageArray[5];
                        break;
                    case 38:
                        sprite.Image = imageArray[6];
                        break;
                    case 40:
                        sprite.Image = imageArray[7];
                        break;
                }
                previousImage = false;
                break;

        }
    }
```

code2:

```
        protected int xPos = 0, yPos = 0, size = 28;

    public Image Image
    {
        get { return image; }
        set { image = value; }
    }


    public int YPos
    {
        get { return yPos; }
        set { yPos = value; }
    }

    public int XPos
    {
        get { return xPos; }
        set { xPos = value; }
    }


 public void DrawSprites(Graphics drawArea)
    {
        drawArea.DrawImage(Image, xPos, yPos, size, size);
    }
```

When I debug, and the console runs the moveUser method, the set propertie Xpos, YPos and Image get changed. But when the drawSprites method runs, those variables are back 0 or the original assigned value. I need to make them permantly changed so I can move my little yellow friend.

note: not all code has been pasted, only the one which is needed, if you need more code just ask.

note 2: User is a subclass from Sprite

Thanks for your time

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `sprites.Drawsprites` and inspect the values there. If they're 0 then you're not modifying the correct instance of sprites in `moveUser`

Answer (score 2):

It does not magically goes back to 0.

You're most likely creating a new object instead of keeping the same one all the way. So the issue is not located in the code you posted, but in where you use / create / modify objects.